# Azure table Storage, table.Execute Returns invalid entity

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

i am new to azure tables, i just want to create table, insert item and get it back.

i have entity class:

```
public class UserEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Country { get; set; }


    public UserEntity() { }

    public UserEntity(MyUser user)
    {
        this.ID = user.ID.ToString();
        this.Name = user.Name;
        this.Surname = user.Surname;
        this.Email = user.Email;
        this.RegistrationTime = user.RegistrationTime;
        this.Password = user.Password.ToString();
        this.Country = user.Country;

        this.PartitionKey = this.Country.ToString();
        this.RowKey = this.Email;
    }
}
```

to create table I use function:

```
public static void CreateTable()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Azure_Storage_ConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TBUsers");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
```

to insert new entity:

```
public void SaveAsNew()
    {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(this);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Azure_Storage_ConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TBUsers");

        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(user);
        var res = table.Execute(insertOperation);
    }
```

both creation and insert works fine (at least dont throw exception and table.Execute returns correct entity)

but i have problem wehn i want to get my item. code looks like this

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Settings.Azure_Storage_ConnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TBUsers");
         TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<UserEntity>(pkey, rkey);
        TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
```

retrievedResult.Result - is an weird UserEntity object. its PartitionKey and RowKey is fine but other properties are either null or 0 (default values).

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So the entity returned from `table.Execute` has the properties set, but the one later retrieved doesn't? Are you sure the RowKey and PartitionKey you're using in the query are precisely the same as the one that you're using on the insert?

Comment: Before insert UserEntity is filled correctly, and table.Execute(insertOperation) returns correct Entity. So I think That insert is correct.
keys are correct, because when I entered invalid key it just returnd null object. 
when I have correct key it returns UserEntity object but with unessigned properties

Comment: I found reason. some entities was not inserted correctly because i had mistake first time. entity's set modifiers were private and because of it their values were not saved in table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a default constructor to create the UserEntity instance. Add a default constructor and try again